# Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::substr()

Tags: codeigniter

When i try to update user record, i get this error "Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::substr()". As far as i investigate form validation return error for email.

```
if($this->input->post('stu_emailid')){
$this->form_validation->set_rules('stu_emailid', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|edit_unique[users.user_email.user_id.' . $student_user_id . ']|edit_unique[student.stu_emailid.student_id.' . $user_id . ']',
array(
        'required'      => 'You have not provided %s.',
        'is_unique'     => 'This %s already exists.'
));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`edit_unique` is not a Rule for CI form validation, it should be `is_unique`

```
if($this->input->post('stu_emailid')){
$this->form_validation->set_rules('stu_emailid', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.user_email.user_id.' . $student_user_id . ']|is_unique[student.stu_emailid.student_id.' . $user_id . ']',
array(
        'required'      => 'You have not provided %s.',
        'is_unique'     => 'This %s already exists.'
));
```